# How to set level for logging in python from configuration file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I am trying to set loggers for my python code, I want to set the level of the log from the configuration file. But unable to do by me. Here the code is given below, If you noticed that in the given below code can see **logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)**. I don't want to directly mention as a hardcoded value **logging.INFO**. Need to get this from the config file, is it possible?

```
    import logging
    from logging.config import fileConfig
    from datetime import date


    class Log:
        @staticmethod
        def trace():
            today = date.today()

            # dd/mm/YY
            d1 = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

            # Gets or creates a logger
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

            # set log level
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

            # define file handler and set formatter
            file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/'+d1+'_logfile.log')
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s')
            file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

            # add file handler to logger
            logger.addHandler(file_handler)

            console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            logger.addHandler(console_handler)
            return logger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use Python built-in [Configuration file parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Have the log levels in a config file and read that value. Since that value will be in string, you can define the dictionary mapping in your code. See below for an example.

```
    import configparser
    config= configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('configfile')
    log_level_info = {'logging.DEBUG': logging.DEBUG, 
                        'logging.INFO': logging.INFO,
                        'logging.WARNING': logging.WARNING,
                        'logging.ERROR': logging.ERROR,
                        }
    print(config['DEFAULT']['LOG_LEVEL'])
    my_log_level_from_config = config['DEFAULT']['LOG_LEVEL']
    my_log_level = log_level_info.get(my_log_level_from_config, logging.ERROR)
    logger.setLevel(my_log_level)
```

Your config file would be like below:

```
user@Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$ cat configfile 
[DEFAULT]
LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO 

user@Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope this is one of the ways to solve the issue. But in case of this line formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s') . It is not possible correct?

Comment: Why not? levelname is put there by Python logging class and not you. So it will work. It just indicates that levelname of that log line has to be printed. So `logger.info()` and `logger.error` will put a line saying `INFO: info message log` or `ERROR error message log`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need a way to set your logging level at runtime instead of a hard-coded value. I would say you have two options.

The first solution would be to parse your configuration file, and set the level of logging accordingly. If you don't want to parse it everytime the `Log` class is invoked, in your main you can set a variable that you pass to the `Log` class.

The second one, that I also suggest, would be to set handlers with python logging class https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html

Comment: The code posted here makes no sense though: normally you set up all the logging system at some starting point, then you use it, but it's configured all along. You don't re-configure the logging system every time you access a logger.

Comment: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` inside a `trace` method makes very little sense either, the point of this pattern is to create a logger for *the current Python module*, so you'd do that once per module *in the module itself*, otherwise you'll always get the exact same logger, which is the one matching wherever the `Log` class (which also seems completely useless) is defined.

Comment: To sum up, this looks a lot like an xy problem at best (where the OP posted the wrong snippet entirely), and at worst it's a case of "not even wrong" where the starting point is so not right in any way there's no way to incrementally fix it.

Comment: @Masklinn you do have a point. I do not know exactly what the OP is up to. And that is why I reshaped his/her question into "runtime logging change with python".

Comment: For which I believe handlers might be of help. And also the same reason why I didn't share any code snippet...can't really understand the OP architecture.

Answer (score -1):

logging level (logging.INFO) is an integer value. can you pass numbers from your config file to set log level

```
print(logging.INFO)
print(logging.WARN)
print(logging.DEBUG)
print(logging.ERROR)
```

20
30
10
40