# Detecting a variable and get its value in a setup script

Tags: python, configuration

So, I have started developing a `Python` package and wanted some help on it. I wanted to know how I can get the value of a variable in a setup script.

So, the user makes a setup script and defines a bunch of variables. How do I get the values of the variable and use it for further steps.

I've noticed this in modules such as `Django` where we define a bunch of `variables` in the `settings.py` file, like: `DEBUG = True` , `INSTALLED_APPS=[<app1>, <app2>]`.

So could anyone guide me through the process of getting the values of the variables. Thanks.

EDIT:

According to my research, I need to use a config file as pointed out in the comments and then parse through it. Which file format would be the easiest to implement, `.cfg`, `.yml`, `.json` or `.ini`?

Comment: Do you mean how to use a config file?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: You can use my answer from these two questions: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330246/14904573 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117268/how-to-set-level-for-logging-in-python-from-configuration-file/66117705#66117705

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!